# How to make a function generic for various, highly similar types?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a linked list format that is of various types (`int`, `double`, for instance):

```
struct DblNode {
    double value;
    DblNode * next;
}
struct IntNode {
    int value;
    IntNode * next;
}
```

And now I am doing things to these lists, and I run into the issue that I am constantly copying and pasting functions, making minor type edits:

```
DblNode * dbl_listind(DblNode * head,int ind){
    DblNode * position = head;
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < ind){
        position = position -> next;
        counter++;
    }
    return position;
}
```

And then duplicating for `int`.

Is there a way to somehow have a generalized list type, and then somehow specify this functionality, independent of the type of the value member of my linked list?

Comment: You mean templates?

Comment: @Rakete1111 sure, I don't know about that (new to c++) but preferably something from scratch, like this. Very simple..

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/460/templates

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` if you *really* need the semantics of a linked list.

Comment: @ChristianHackl for sure.  that will be next weekend :)  Right now, I'm just going for a faster implementation of code I wrote in python, and also a c++ learning opportunity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what class/function templates supposed to do. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
    T value;
    Node * next;
}

template <typename T>
Node<T> * listind(Node<T> * head,int ind){
    Node<T> * position = head;
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < ind){
        position = position -> next;
        counter++;
    }
    return position;
}

// optional
using DblNode = Node<double>;
using IntNode = Node<int>;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Quick question: Do I define the entire template in the header file? Or split across header and .cpp file?

Comment: @bordeo [Better in header file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file).